# Typeahead and Ember.handelbars

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, typeahead.js

I am trying to implement Typeahead with an elasticsearch backend. The search itself seems to be working, now I am trying to tweak the optic. I would like to use a Ember.Handlebars helper that I wrote. My first attempt was using handelbars as template engine:

```
App.SearchComponent = Ember.TextField.extend({

  didInsertElement: function() {
    App.UserSearchEngine.initialize();
    this.initializeTypeahead();
  },

  initializeTypeahead: function(){
      var _this = this;
      this.typeahead = this.$().typeahead({
          hint: true,
          highlight: true,
          minLength: 3
        },
        {
         name: _this.$().attr('id') || "typeahead",
         // template: 'My: {{firstName}}',
         limit: this.get("limit") || 5,
         source: App.UserSearchEngine.ttAdapter(),
         templates:{
            suggestion: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{firstName}} {{lastName}}')
         }
        }
      );
  }

});
```

This is giving me an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'container' of undefined
>   caused by Ember in the "_triageMustache" helper in the line

```
 var helper = Ember.Handlebars.resolveHelper(options.data.view.container, property);
```

This is probably due to the fact that I try to compile a template directly.

If I would use Handlebars.compile() instead of Ember.Handlebars.compile() it would work. It seems that the context is not correct.

Comment: Any news on this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually should use regular `Handlebars.compile` here. The Typeahead library doesn't know anything about Ember bound templates, so it doesn't know how to invoke them.

Alternatively, your template is so simple it could just be a literal function, to save yourself the hassle of shipping a Handlebars compiler in production or precompiling this one specially:

```
templates: {
  suggestion: function(context){ return context.firstName + ' ' + context.lastName; }
}
```